# If the Imperius Curse gives you a blank look, why was there doubt over whether someone was under it?

Tags: harry-potter, unforgivable-curse

In the books, many of Voldemort's Death Eaters, such as Lucius Malfoy, avoided imprisonment after the first Wizarding War by claiming that they were acting under the influence of the Imperius Curse. The film version of *Goblet of Fire* has Mad Eye Moody succinctly explaining the dilemma.

> "Scores of witches and wizards have claimed that they only did You-Know-Who's bidding under the influence of the Imperius Curse. But here's the rub: how do we sort out the liars?"

However, this makes no sense in the film because those under the Imperius Curse have a blank look with obviously wrong eyes.

[image: Viktor Krum under the Imperius Curse in *Goblet of Fire*]

And in *Deathly Hallows, Part I*, a goblin has a dopey, blank face after being under the Imperius Curse.

[image]

So if people under the Imperius Curse have a blank look, why is there doubt that they were under it?

I'd like an answer that respects film continuity (rather than just being "the films are terrible").

Comment: I have no evidence of this, but I suspect that the blank look is only when the person controlling them hasn’t ordered them to “act normally.”

Comment: If people were suspicious every time someone had a blank look, they would get the impression that the whole Ministerium of Magic was under the Imperius Curse. But then again, they were probably right, especially in Deathly Hallows.

Comment: *Out-of-Universe*: The director needed a mechanic to show the audience that the person was controlled by someone else. While it is revealed in the book later on, the film can't waste to much time on that. An appropriate method seemed to be changing the eye-colour to make them blank. Although I can't remember where, I'm very certain that I have seen this symbolism of blank eyes being used to depict someone not capable of controlling their actions/being controlled by somebody else before. But again, *this is out-of-universe*. If someone is willing to expand this and making it to an answer, feel

Comment: [cont'd] free to do so. Sadly, I don't have the time or the means to do the research necessary right now.

Comment: To add to Narusan's comment: the in-universe answer might be that they don't *really* go blank like that, and it's something only the audience can "see". That sort of thing is not unheard-of; for example, in the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode ["The Naked Now"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now), the audience hears a sound effect whenever someone gets infected.

Comment: Unless the people are caught red-handed doing Voldemort's bidding, an argument could be made that they *were* under the influence of this curse when they did whatever they were accused of, but that the spell was somehow broken before they were caught.

Comment: If we're just focusing on the films, then, is it ever actually confirmed that Krum is under the Imperius Curse at the time, and not some other enchantment? Because if he isn't--or if he's, say, under some variant of the curse that doesn't require him to pretend to fit in--then that would explain that case. Indeed, the milky-eye effect does not occur with Bogrod, supporting this idea. Bogrod's own case can of course be explained by Harry and Ron's relative inexperience with the curse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we are focusing just on the movies here, the answer is obvious.

**In-universe.**

The 2 people were **not** under the imperious curse. That's just an assumption the viewer jumps to having seen the unforgivables performed earlier.

> HARRY: No stop! He's bewitched Cedric. *They struggle.*
>
> CEDRIC: Get off me!
>
> HARRY: He's bewitched!

Note that it doesn't imply or mention the Imperious curse at all. I'm not sure what was used on the Goblin but its possible it was Confundus charm (like in the books). In fact the only 100% guaranteed use of Imperious I remember in the films is with the spider in class, (and that spider looked exactly the same: perfectly normal). So as an In-universe answer no humans were under Imperious curse in the film at all: they were all probably under a different curse. *NOTE: this explanation only works for the films but the question specifically limits to just the films.*

**Out of Universe**

There had to be a way to show the viewer the person was under someone else's control. The eyes are the easiest way to do this as others have pointed out already.

**Conclusion**

I see no evidence in the films to suggest the Imperious Curse changes some-ones physical appearance. Therefor while its implied to the viewer after the class demo, it was never once confirmed other than the viewer assuming that's the curse controlling them, (we never see the curse used on those with milky eyes: so we don't know for sure what curse was used). **If there is only truly the spider which we see onscreen then its safe to assume that the Imperious Cure doesn't create a blank look or milky eyes: and anyone under that curse looks perfectly normal.** The books are harder to explain away though.

Its been a while since I've seen the films so I could be mistaken on some details please feel free to point them out.

Comment: Imperio was also used in the bank; the difference in the film is that Ron also does it whereas in the book only Harry does (he casts it on the goblin as well as Travers). Not in the film either is McGonagall using it on one of the Carrow siblings (just after Harry cast Crucio on the brother).

Comment: Hey, *you* try to fit a spider with white contact lenses!

Comment: @Pryftan You’re very right about that - it definitely *was* the Imperius Curse that was used in Gringotts, including in the movie.

Comment: Is Crouch Sr not under the Imperius Curse throughout most of _GoF_ in the movie? In the book, we see him several times while he’s Imperiused.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in the movie its not clear whether he is or isn't, just that he gets murdered (it looks like he found something out and was killed to shut him up). Its been awhile since I've watched the movies so I might have missed the Gringotts scene, but it could be that it works different on goblins

Comment: @Matt Unless I’m misremembering the course of events in the book, Crouch is already Imperiused when we see him at the first Triwizard events. I haven’t seen the films in ages, but isn’t Crouch there for the first Triwizard things in the films as well?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet he is there in the films at the first event too but I don't remember anything in the movie to suggest (or even imply) he was being controlled. The books make it very clear he is being controlled so you are right there, this question though was asking about the movies only so in answering it I ignored the books. There's a lot the movies left out or just skipped over

Comment: Yes, that was part of my original question: does Crouch Jr not specify in the film when his father was Imperiused when he’s confessing at the end?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet no he doesn't, here's a you tube link https://youtu.be/LjcCstYDDlo for that scene - the movies left it out of the confession, if you want to continue this I'm happy to in chat

Comment: @Bellatrix Thanks. Not been very well (and yet another - fourth - death in the family and very worried about my girlfriend too) so not been around here at all. You're right of course but in the book Harry also casts the Imperius Curse on Travers as well. He also Confunds (iirc that's the word) the guards in the bank so as to make sure they believe they already checked the lot.

Comment: @Pryftan You’re welcome. Sorry to hear that about your family, girlfriend and life in general though. Hopefully things will improve for you soon. :) Yes, in the book Harry’s the only one who uses the Imperius Curse in Gringotts, and he Confunds the guards before that. The movie does differ from the book somewhat, just not in the use of the Imperius Curse.

Comment: @Bellatrix Thank you for the kind words etc. :) Means a lot to me - as does our dialogues here actually. It's going to be a long journey but she'll make it through in the end and that cannot come too soon but it won't be soon unfortunately. And yes what you say about the book versus the film is true but I would go further than that: the film is so utterly unfaithful to canon that .. Well at least I can sometimes watch it unlike Jackson's The Lord of the Rings; I can't watch even 20 minutes at a time without turning it off in utter disgust. The epilogue has at least 20 errors even! But yes.

Comment: @Pryftan You’re very welcome! :) I’m glad you enjoy talking to me, I enjoy talking to you as well! Hopefully both you and your girlfriend make it through whatever she’s going through well, and the end of it comes sooner than expected. I fully agree with you about the movie (though I do like their portrayal of ‘me’ as she looks and acts more like me than I could’ve hoped, and seeing the wizarding world as I don’t have a good visual imagination), it changes events quite a bit. What particularly annoyed me was making *Half-Blood Prince* more about romance while removing the Dark Lord’s origins.

Comment: @Bellatrix Means a lot to me that you enjoy our talking too :) My girlfriend - well it's a very complicated story but I just have to hold on and remember that she's far stronger and braver than she knows (and she sees this in me just as I do her). As for HBP I agree. It would have been far more entertaining and instructive too. Instead Harry hears the whispering in DH films for finding the Horcruxes. As I’m watching a film in my mind I’m simultaneously reading the book as well and that can be good but it's more of a problem after a while. But unless there's private chat here I best stop :(

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks a lot! :) Good luck to both you and your girlfriend, hopefully you’ll both make it through whatever the trouble is. That’s true, they substituted the whispering thing for Harry actually having learned where the Horcruxes were. While it’s true he had a mental link with the Dark Lord which did help him, he also had background information from Dumbledore which was important to the story. I’m not sure if there’s any private chat here, but I’d be glad to talk with you more if there’s any way.

Comment: @Bellatrix Yes. And you know it makes me think as if he has schizophrenia... The whispering voices etc. It's ridiculous. Also there is this that I thought of several hours ago: why didn't Harry in the film CoS hear whispering of the diary? That makes no sense at all. And thank you for the kind thoughts. I'll try and find out if there's a way for private chat here.

Comment: @Pryftan Yes, as it’s portrayed in the movie, it does seem more like schizophrenia than a connection with the Dark Lord or his Horcruxes. That’s a good point - he didn’t hear the diary whispering, so it’s inconsistent with what happens in DH. You’re very welcome, and hopefully you’ll find one! :)

Answer (score 9):

## The Imperius Curse *can* cause a blank look - but doesn’t always.

Someone under the Imperius Curse looking blank doesn’t contradict the books at all - it’s shown to be possible. In the books, there are cases where being Imperiused causes a blank look. When Harry uses the Imperius Curse on Travers and Bogrod, they both end up looking blank.

> “They’re Imperiused,’ he added, in response to Hermione and Ron’s confused queries about Travers and Bogrod, who were both now standing there looking blank. ‘I don’t think I did it strongly enough, I don’t know …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)*</sup></sub>

In the movie, Harry also uses Imperio, as he had in the book, and it causes the same blank look.

> None see Harry’s hand slip from the cloak, his wand pointed at Bogrod.
>
> HARRY (O.S.)
>   
> *Imperio.*
>
> The door glides shut. The wind dies. Bogrod blinks.
>
> BOGROD
>   
> Very well, Madam Lestrange. If you will follow me. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 2](https://www.scribd.com/doc/163084623/HARRY-POTTER-AND-THE-DEATHLY-HALLOWS-PART-2-by-screenplay-Steve-Kloves)*</sup></sub>

This is likely because the Imperius Curse was performed poorly, but it *can* cause a blank look. A well-executed Imperius Curse doesn’t seem to have any external evidence, since Dumbledore (a very powerful wizard) was unable to tell that Madame Rosmerta was under it.

Krum and the goblin were likely under less-well-cast Imperius Curses, giving them both an obvious blank look. The goblin looked blank in the book as well as the movie, and Harry certainly wasn’t experienced in casting Unforgivable Curses, so that’s consistent across both. We also know for sure that the spell used on the goblin in the movie *was* in fact Imperio, since we hear it cast. In the book, Barty Crouch Jr. says he Imperiused Krum, which is still consistent with the spell he used in the movie, if he did it hastily or didn’t cast it well enough where it was unnoticeable. Krum isn’t mentioned as looking blank in the book, but it is possible for him to look that way under the Imperius Curse.

Comment: It's possible though that Dumbledore kept silent because he didn't want to alarm Harry and also because he knew what Draco was to do; he also knew the Order would be there (Draco even complains about them at the tower) and he knew that Severus would do everything to act both sides too. I think he was surprised about the Death Eaters though but it seems to me that's not something he would have given too much thought about with the other things considered.

Comment: Also would Krum be under a not-so-powerful instance of Imperio? We're talking about Barty Crouch Jr., after all, who iirc also used it on the real Mad-Eye.

Comment: @Pryftan Barty was a bit busy at the time, he might not have worried about getting the spell just right as long as it did the job.

Comment: @JAB Well sure you could say that. You could say a lot of things though. But personally I would take the last part of your comment and say that's the key: he only needed it to do the job; busy or not is irrelevant as he had a job to do and he did it well too.

Comment: @Pryftan That’s true - he wouldn’t want to let on to Harry exactly what was going on. The reason I think Dumbledore didn’t know is he seemed actually surprised when he realized that Rosmerta was under the Imperius Curse.

Comment: @Miss Bella Good point. I have this memory of that now. He didn't know that she was under the Imperius Curse did he? He knew that Draco had been ordered by Voldemort to kill him (Dumbledore) and so all the bad things that happened (Harry's recklessness and frankly stupidity in casting a curse marked 'For Enemies' notwithstanding) he knew Draco was behind it but he also relied on Severus to try and keep a watch on things too. But it makes sense what you say: if he didn't know about the Death Eaters why would he know about the Imperius Curse? Did Severus know about the DE's even? Perhaps not?

Comment: @Pryftan Yes, Dumbledore figures it out while talking to Draco about his attempts to kill him. *“We all like appreciation for our own hard work, of course … but you must have had an accomplice, all the same … someone in Hogsmeade, someone who was able to slip Katie the – the – aaaah …’ Dumbledore closed his eyes again and nodded, as though he was about to fall asleep. ‘… of course … Rosmerta. How long has she been under the Imperius Curse?” - Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 27 (The Lightning-Struck Tower)* Draco also says he didn’t tell Snape his plan to bring Death Eaters in.

Comment: @Miss Bella I remember that vaguely yes. As for something you noted in your answer: *and Harry certainly wasn’t experienced in casting Unforgivable Curses* Yes although in the end he still did all right and your mocking of him at the Ministry certainly helped him master Crucio as he demonstrates and even acknowledges you (a source of pride for you, maybe, if you knew) and your wisdom at Hogwarts! I feel the fact he did fine means the targets were rather susceptible to it. I imagine too that Harry couldn't Imperius his clone! :) If he could ignore Voldemort's Imperius then I’m sure of that...

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers for Harry Potter Book 4 ahead!

---

> In the 4th book after the reveal that Barty Crouch Jr. was Mad-Eye Moody all along, the reader can go back a few pages and re-read the Labyrinth scene and see what was done by Barty Crouch Jr. to help Harry Potter to win.

In films and especially movie theatres, it is not as easy to rewind the tape. Most of all, you'd have to convince everyone else there that doing so was a good idea.

Therefore, the filmmakers needed a method to show beforehand whether someone was under the Imperius curse or not.

Doing something with the eyes is a common  symbolism to depict someone not capable of controlling their actions/being controlled by somebody else before. Zombies are the best example here, they are "not themselves" but controlled by the desire for human meat.

Just take a look at MJ before going Zombie and after in the Thriller music video and notice the change with the eyes.

[image: Michael before going Zombie]
[image: Michael after going Zombie]

Comment: I think this only partly answers the question. See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160543/was-stan-shunpike-under-the-imperius-curse-during-the-deathly-hallows), where the "strangely blank look" on Stan Shurpike's face was enough to identify him being under the spell. And on top of that, Harry notices this immediately, even though it is night and he is busy with other things :)

Comment: @PhilippFlenker You're correct. I have edited my answer to remove the in-universe explanation. The conflict with the *Stan Shurpike question* still remains, as that was in the books, not in a movie. I'm trying to fix that too now.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker Yes.. But it does rather complement the answers well. Of course Harry did recognise it and there might have been other examples too but since the question does refer to the films. I still would say the right answer is the one the questioner didn't want: *The films are terrible.* At least canonically it's the right answer... Sort of.

Answer (score 1):

I like to give a short answer:

In the film adaptation of 'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire,

The Imperius Curse appears to give the victim's eyes a milky, glazed appearance which is not mentioned in the books and would decrease the curse's effectiveness, since it would be easily detectable. However, it's possible that this is a sign of a poorly or hastily performed curse, or one where the victim is actively resisting.

Comment: I don't think Barty Crouch Jr. would perform an Imperius Curse only poorly. Furthermore, your answer raises the question why no-one in the Ministerium of Magic was resisting the Imperius Curse, as there were no reported incidents of "blank faces".

Comment: @Narusan Certainly not all the time. After all he successfully helped Harry master shaking it off to also shake off Voldemort's curse.